# Fitnesse - Can I make an existing wiki page a subwiki?

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to create a test suite of some of the existing pages I have developed using fitnesse. Does the tool support to change or refactor the pages to sub-wikis to make a part of newly created test suite?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question exactly.

You can refactor a test suite to be "reparented" to another wiki.  Just go to the page and select the "refactor" button.  In the text box, select the new parent page path in the form of "MyWiki.MySubPage.EtcEtc".

Comment: Hi, I don't know why but I could not able to refactor a page successfully yet. Everytime I try to do that it gives an error message as - Cannot rename page ... as...

Comment: Are you sure the new name is a valid Wiki word?

Answer (score 0):

You can use symbolic links for that.

Click Properties on the sidebar, then at the bottom you can symlink your pages from other suites into the suite.

This feature can be used also to run tests with different setup/teardown variations.